# I saw 2 GPU indicators, Could it be the cause that I keep failing to install tensorflow-GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

I'd tried dozen times to install tensorflow-GPU, but all failed, thougth I followed the instructions indicated by those who successfully installed.
I just noticed that I have 2 GPU indicators, meaning I have 2 GUP set? One Intel and one Nvidia.

Could it be the reason? If so, how can I kick in the proper one (Nvidia)?
Thanks for advice.
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Verify proper installation of tensorflow-GPU by using following steps,

- Can you check if tensorflow is using GPU,

  `import tensorflow as tf
  print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())`
- To find out which device is used, you can enable log device placement
  like this:

  `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`
- you can try to assign a computation to the gpu and see whether you have an error

  `import tensorflow as tf
  with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
      a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
      b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
      c = tf.matmul(a, b)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      print (sess.run(c))`
- Check the GPU usage using
  `nvidia-smi`